# Uninstall ROS fully on OS X

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How I uninstall ROS, Catkin, all ROS packages, and all other ROS-specific dependencies?

I'm on OS X, and installed ROS Groovy according to http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104416/uninstall-ros-fully-on-os-x/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the following shell code to print out the commands that will remove all the known system dependencies installed for ROS packages:

```
rosdep db | awk '{if ($3) print $3}' | { while read package; do [ "$package" == "->" ] || (brew info $package &> /dev/null && echo "brew remove $package") || (pip list | grep $package &> /dev/null  && echo "pip uninstall $package") || echo "# $package is neither brew formula or a python package"; done; }
```

This will print out one line for each system dependency needed by ROS with the appropriate command for its removal. This does not actually remove the packages as I think this is unwise. Many system dependencies needed by ROS are likely also needed by other software on your system, so you need to evaluate on an individual package basis, what should be uninstalled.

The ROS python tools can be uninstall with:

```
pip uninstall wstool rosdep rosinstall rosinstall_generator rospkg catkin-pkg
```

Other than this your ROS installation should be self contained under your ROS workspace directory, or where ever you have placed your ROS installation.

---

Originally posted by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) with karma: 316 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-11-25**:
Thanks for the answer. As it happens I already went ahead and removed it manually (using rm and pip uninstall). I found there were a few other dependencies like Catkin, which is strewn around /usr/local, but this looks like a a relatively compact way if I need to do it in the future. Thanks agina.